# Problem opening a text file in Python

Tags: python

This seems like it should be very easy:

```
f = open('C:\Users\john\Desktop\text.txt', 'r')
```

But I am getting this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    f = open('C:\Users\john\Desktop\text.txt', 'r')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\\Users\robejohn\\Desktop\text.txt'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your file name has backslash characters in it. Backslash is the escape character in Python strings. Either replace them with `'/'` characters or use `r'C:\Users\john\Desktop\text.txt'`.

You might also find the functions in [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) useful.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows, paths use backslash. But if a string that must represent a path contains characters such as **'\r'** , **'\t'** , **'\n'** .... etc  there will be this kind of problem. This is the precise reason why your string fails to represent a path.

In the absence of these problematic characters, there will be no problem. If they are present, you must escape the backslashes or use a raw string `r'C:\Users\john\Desktop\text.txt'`