# using winsound, plays error sound instead of chosen sound

Tags: python, playsound, winsound

I am using winsound to play a swoosh sound:

```
winsound.PlaySound("D:\GamesImade\pythonpong\bounce.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

When I run it with my IDE it works. But if I run the exe file by itself it doesn't work, it plays the windows error sound.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem opening a text file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782321/problem-opening-a-text-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the flag shown below and also the backslash to forward slash

`winsound.PlaySound("D:\GamesImade\pythonpong\bounce.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)`

to

`winsound.PlaySound("D:/GamesImade/pythonpong/bounce.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)`

Comment: I am using turtle, so I am drawing things on the screen so if I remove "winsound.SND_ASYNC" it freezes the screen(as expected) but if I do "winsound.SND_FILENAME" it plays the error sound in the IDE aswell

Comment: hmmm...this might not make a difference, but try switching the slashes in your path.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that was an issue since I copied the path. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ya, it's something I miss all the time with python. if it worked out, be sure to accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a line of code that was supposed to run at a certain point and the code was accurately recognizing when the sound was supposed to be played, but it was only playing a windows error sound.

I changed the code from:

```
winsound.PlaySound("sound.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

To:

```
winsound.PlaySound('C:/Users/username/OneDrive/Desktop/Project Folder/sound.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

So, like the answer I switched the slashes around, but kept the `SND_ASYNC` and that runs in the program.